# iPhone application for non-english language

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, localization

I want to build iPhone application for non-english language and I have read about application localization.

- do I have to support string localization if I'm going to support only one language?
- Will I need to make any changes to project setting to support non-english app?
- I was using UIsearchBar to search data on tableview  using the following code and it worked fine with english strings and failed with other, any idea why this is happening?

.

```
for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice : use NSLocalizedString, even if you're not planning to translate your application for now... The day you will it will be localization-ready.

Edit : and yes, you have to modify the info.plist to set the "main language" for the project...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need localization if you are going to have only one language, just create app in that language and submit it.

What error do you get when it fails on UISearchBar

Comment: I don't get an error I just don't get search result for the string I'm searching for although it is on the list.

Comment: You can try first to NSLog search string to see that you are receiving it right, maybe some encoding stuff or something similar. Then you can try also to split string with pathComponents and to compare strings in array with search string.